# Why is argv parameter to execvp not const?

Tags: c, libc, execvp

execvp is defined thus:

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

Which precludes code such as this from being used:

```
const char* argv[] = {"/bin/my", "command", "here", NULL};
execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

Was this an accidental omission?  Is it safe to const_cast around this?  Or do some execvp implementations actually scribble on that memory?

Comment: Although the `exec*` family of functions does not modify its arguments as noted in the POSIX specification, do note that on Windows, [`CreateProcess` requires a writable command line](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/01/9673254.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The POSIX spec says (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html):

> The `argv[]` and `envp[]` arrays of pointers and the strings to which those arrays point shall not be modified by a call to one of the exec functions, except as a consequence of replacing the process image.

<strike>I think the missing (or misplaced) `const` is simply an historical oddity.</strike>

Comment: The missing `const` isn't a historical oddity; rather, it's because you can't convert from a `char**` to a `const char* const*` in C without a cast (but you *can* in C++).

Comment: @Adam: right.  That's the answer to the first question in the post. I spaced on that: http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html

Comment: See also the RATIONALE section at the end of the POSIX spec for exec. It explains the choice of const omission.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Then the standard should add a separate #ifdef __cplusplus declaration that allows C++ program to be const correct.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this same situation. Because execvp() has a `char *const` as the second parameter, that means it accepts a constant pointer to a char. Therefore, if you pass it a pointer char it will be able to cast the pointer char to a constant pointer to a char. So, instead of declaring it

```
const char* argv[] = {"/bin/my", "command", "here", NULL};
```

try

```
char* argv[] = {"/bin/my", "command", "here", NULL};
```

and it will accept `argv[]` without issue.

Comment: I meant pointer constant to a char. I went ahead and corrected the grammar mistake.

Comment: That just moves the error/warning from the `execvp()` line to the assignment statement (unless you have a very lenient compiler).

Comment: I tested with both gcc and clang using the -Wall option. It didn't return any errors for me.

Comment: My usual command (`gcc  -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds`) gives `warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type`